# Why does splitting on `(?!^)` and `(?<!^)` produce the same answer?

Tags: java, regex

The following two lines of code:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("test".split("(?<!^)")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("test".split("(?!^)")));
```

each produce the same output:

```
[t, e, s, t]
```

I expected the bottom line to produce

```
[, t, e, s, t]
```

since it should be willing to split after the `^` and before the `t`. Can someone point out where my thinking is wrong?

Comment: Actually, I would have expected both to return `[t, e, s, t, ]`...

Comment: @TimPietzcker `split` by default ignores the trailing whitespaces. This - `split("(?<!)", -1)` would give that result.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: That is a pretty random "feature" of `split()`, I agree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(?!^)` matches any position that's not at the start of the string, just as `(?<!^)`. Since the  `^` anchor doesn't have any length, it is irrelevant whether you look forward or backwards.

Imagine the string `test` like this where `|` denotes the positions *between*  the characters:

```
|  t  |  e  |  s  |  t  |
^ matches here         ($ matches here)
```

`(?!^)` doesn't match at position `0` because the regex engine "sees" the start of string from here when looking forward by 0 characters

`(?<!^)` doesn't match here either because the regex engine "sees" the start of string from here when looking backwards by 0 characters

Comment: You have different regexes in the two cases.